# Getting null when trying to copy values to pointer str

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a function named read_line() to gets data from a text file, line by line. After calling the function, the line would be written to str pointer and the function will return the length of the line. Unfortunately, I ended up getting null all the time.

```
/* readline.c*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "readline.h"

int read_line(char *str)
{
    /* Open the file for reading */
    size_t line_buf_size = 0;
    ssize_t line_size;
    FILE *fp = fopen("0.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file '%s'\n", "0.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Get the first line of the file. */
    line_size = getline(&str, &line_buf_size, fp);
    printf(str);
    return line_size - 2;
}

    /* main.c*/
#include "readline.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    int num;
    num = read_line(str);
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("%d", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected: get the content of the first line of the text file.
Actual: (null)12

Comment: The pointer named `str` is NULL when you created it, and you are not passing it to any kind of function that can change it, so it will be NULL when you try to use it with printf.  Maybe you need to pass a pointer to `str` into `getline` instead of copying the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`, you have an object named `str` of type `char*`. `read_line` takes the value of the pointer as a parameter, but does not modify the pointer itself. This means that no matter what happens, the value of `str` will still be `NULL` when it reaches the `printf`s in `main`

One approach would be to pass a pointer to your pointer object, instead of its value.

```
int read_line(char **str)
{
  ...
  /* Get the first line of the file. */
  line_size = getline(str, &line_buf_size, fp);
  printf("%s", *str);
  ...
}
```

This way, `str` will be modified by `getline`